# url action controller not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I got this error after publishing the application to the Ubuntu 18 server. I already read around some solutions online but it's really complicated and in my view is different from my problem.
This error is shown in Firefox. In Chrome the error message is GET http://serverIP/controller/sweetalertCss net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

So I have this code in the index.php file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?=base_url('controller/bootstrapJs')?>"></script>
```

that should call the controller function bootstrapJs() and redirect to readfile(BASEPATH . BOOTSRAP_JS) to execute the link /../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js but for some reason, its working in my localhost but not in the server.

Hope someone can help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: check file permissions. Had that similar issue once before

Comment: And also check the file is there or not?

Comment: already checked the file permission, set them to 777, same error.. and yes, already checked if the files were there and they were.. all of it.. I have 10 JS files with the same error..

Comment: Filenames / Folders are all case sensitive on a Linux box if that is what your server is running.